# The hierarchy of the type MainActivity is inconsistent. Why?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, runtime-error

I start saying "I hate eclipse". Yesterday: My project goes well without any error. All perfect! Ok, i closed eclipse, shutted down my pc and i went bed. Today: i start my eclipse and surprise!!! 10000000 errors in 5 my projects! All says when i pass with mouse over the MainActivity, or another activity;

`The hierarchy of the type MainActivity is inconsistent`.

Now, i'm going crazy because i need these projects! Please can anyone help me? This situation is so annoying.

EDIT: looking at console i get this:

```
Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-10-25 10:21:44 - AppTemplate] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-10-25 10:21:44 - AppTemplate] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-10-25 10:21:44 - AppTemplate] Versions found are:
[2013-10-25 10:21:44 - AppTemplate] Path: C:\Users\davide\Desktop\MyAppbattstats\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-10-25 10:21:44 - AppTemplate]     Length: 556198
[2013-10-25 10:21:44 - AppTemplate]     SHA-1: 4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
[2013-10-25 10:21:44 - AppTemplate] Path: C:\Users\davide\Desktop\SlidingMenu-master\library\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-10-25 10:21:44 - AppTemplate]     Length: 385685
[2013-10-25 10:21:44 - AppTemplate]     SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
[2013-10-25 10:21:44 - AppTemplate] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Comment: clean & rebuild once.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459930/the-hierarchy-of-the-type-mainactivity-is-inconsistent

Comment: Try to clean your project.

Comment: Project -> Clean -> (Select projects you want to clean, check Start a build immediately) -> OK

Comment: Press ALT > Menu Bar > Project > Dropdown > Clean.

Comment: same problem after clean

Comment: look please at my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a third-party library or the android v7 appcompat library,a lot of libraries have a version of the android support library.Now you have to remove the android v4 support library from the libs folder of your project,ensure that the library has added to your project and compile again.

Eclipse is a utitlity tool that manages a lot of things for you,if you do not like eclipse you can use the command-line and ant for creating Android applications.

Looking at your console output it looks like you are using the SlidingMenu library.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you include two versions of the Android support library, `android-support-v4.jar`. Make sure to include only one. I would remove the jar that came with the SlidingMenu library, and use the one that is inside your libs folder.

Edit: this causes your 100000 errors, because everything that uses the support library will fail now, and everything depending on that as well. Probably a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case after adding the v4 support library in the project this error remove.
Go to project properties.>> Build java path >> Library >> browse library android-support-v4.jar >> ok
Then  clean the project .
Error remove